# Probability a value exceeding another

Tags: probability

I am trying to create a formula in microsoft excel that will tell the percentage a particular value (x) is above another value (y).

I can do the formula manually, for example:

One person has a 80% chance of making a goal, the other person has a 20% chance of making a goal. Each person only gets one try. What is the percent that together they will make 1 or more goals?

Here is what I have

p1=.8  p2=.2

There are 2^2=4 possible combinations

(0,0)=(1-p1)(1-p2)=0.16
(1,0)=(p1)(1-p2)=0.64
(0,1)=(1-p1)(p2)=0.04
(1,1)=(p1)(p2)=0.16

probability that x greater than or equal to 1 = 84%

I am trying to figure an equation where there are 14 different p values. I want to know what the probability there will be x ammount or more goals. I have been stumped trying to figure out a formula that can do this. Any help?

Comment: Please edit your previous question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211926/ instead of posting a copy.

Comment: @PeterFlom: The question you closed this as a duplicate of [has been deleted.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/209965/duplicates-of-deleted-questions) Presumably, this question should be either reopened or also deleted.

Comment: See the reason that one was closed.  I think this would have the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Because, in your case the probabilities of successes aren't equal, all you need is [Poisson binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) and upper tail of its CDF (Cumulative Distribution Function).

Frankly, I don't know if this Poisson binomial is present in Excel, but for sure it's present in R in package poibin.

By the way, you should follow Juho's recommendations and update the previous question rather than start a new one (even with this form of question).